# A Microsoft (R) Visual C# compiler Error showed up in my Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

So I created a new Unity (2019.2.17f1) project and a new error showed up:

[image: Error image]

There is nothing more. Just this. No error source path, nothing. To be honest, looks like an Ad or something. Anyways, is there a way to get rid of it? I have looked for an answer but none showed to be useful (for my situation). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did it compile anyway?

Comment: No, it doesn't  let me. Can't compile it nor launch the game in editor.

Comment: In [another case of that error](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-microsoft-r-visual-c-compiler-version-2-9-1-65535-9d34608e.716471/), there was actually a compiler error in one of the C# files despite not being reported in that output. You may just need to look through the files in your project to see if any errors stand out

Comment: Being a blank project does it go away if you change to .net 4?

Comment: @BugFinder No, sadly.

Comment: Has it been working previously or is this your first unity install on this computer

Comment: @devNull So then it's a bug in unity'ies files, because the project is blank. All there is, is just a sample scene, nothing more.

Comment: @BugFinder It's a new project and I got this error first time. Just opened another project and the same error appeared. It had never appeard before.

Comment: OK so you've been using unity previously?

Comment: @BugFinder Yep, for almost 2 years.

Comment: is this a different location to where you normally store projects? Does it do the same if you turn your anitvirus off?

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, I was. The error popped up and I deleted the old project and created a new one in my usual dir. Just tried to turn off my AV but that didn't work. Right now I'm re-installing my unity, unity hub and VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after looking trough my registry, I found out that I had a key value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

All I needed to do was to clear out the value. That is what fixed it for me.